# How to change row of table when using ng-repeat on a column 'td'(if it is possible)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a table. In head of that, I have 7 columns in a row(sunday, monday ...).
Now in row of tbody I am repeating columns as days (I have 30  day).
It is repeating all 30 items in that single(as we know).
So what I want is, I need only first seven item in that row of body.then next seven in next row and so on..
Solution would be helpful?
Here is my markup

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <th>Sunday</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>                                
</thead>
<tbody>
    <td ng-repeat="day in staticEvents"><span>{{day.title}}</span></td>
</tbody>
```

$scope.staticEvents is an array have 30 objects(API response).

Comment: Why not convert `staticEvents` into an array of arrays having length 7?

Comment: that's what i am doing right now. I was just trying to check if angularjs already has anything(any directive) for this scenario.
if it's there then why would write a lengthy code in my controller.

Comment: Well there might be some calendar plugins, but I don't think there is anything built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle that I hope would help you. You could do this by $index.

```
    <div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="days=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','..']" class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th>Sunday</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="day in days" ng-if="$index % 7 == 0">
        <td class="col">{{days[$index]}}</td>
        <td class="col">{{days[$index + 1]}}</td>
        <td class="col">{{days[$index + 2]}}</td>
        <td class="col">{{days[$index + 3]}}</td>
        <td class="col">{{days[$index + 4]}}</td>
        <td class="col">{{days[$index + 5]}}</td>
        <td class="col">{{days[$index + 6]}}</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/febbgsjn/2/)

Comment: Your answer looks best but I am not getting it with my angularjs version 1.3
I have created a simple app on 1.5 version, with that its working fine.
but my main project(app) is on 1.3 . So I need to update my angular.min.js file.

Comment: Can you suggest me some which work with angularjs 1.3 .

Comment: I got it where was the problem. It was with my data.
Thanks Junaid bhai.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to change your data structure a little. With a simple array it would be difficult to make multi-line table by one iteration of ng-if or ng-switch.
More-over, with this design of data structure, you will have allways Sunday the 1st, Monday the 2nd, ...

Try to make two-dimensional array, where you could prepare your "month" and then go through by two ng-repeats. Something like:

Controller:

```
$scope.month = makeMonth($scope.staticEvents, 3);

function makeMonth(days, firstIndex) {
// days[] - array of days in month 
//fisrstIndex - index of the first day in month: 0=Sunday, ..., 6=Saturday
    if (!angular.isArray(days) || firstIndex < 0 || firstIndex > 6) {
        return [];
    }
    var month = [];
    var row = [];
    for (i=0; i < days.length + firstIndex; i++) {
        var day = {
            title: ""
        };
        if (i >= firstIndex) {
            day = days[i - firstIndex];
        }
        row.push(day);
        if (i % 7 === 6) {
            month.push(row);
            row = [];
        }
    }
    if (row != []) {
        month.push(row);
    }
    return month;
}
```

Template:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>Sunday</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>                                
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in month">
            <td ng-repeat="day in row"><span>{{day.title}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have some specific error? I created a fiddle with even older version 1.0.3 and it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jankovskyp/p79cn7n8/

Comment: try with this data once
['null', 'WeeklyOff', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'WeeklyOff', 'WeeklyOff', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'WeeklyOff', 'WeeklyOff', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'WeeklyOff', 'WeeklyOff', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'General', 'WeeklyOff', 'WeeklyOff', 'General', 'General']

Comment: I was showing some duplicate properties error
So I replaced ' ng-repeat="day in days " '  with ng-repeat="day in days track by $index".
Now its working fine. Thanx for your effort

Comment: Sure, with this data function does not work, becouse from your question it looked like you use an array of objects with property 'title'.